# Why won't my array get inserted into my Database?

Tags: php, database

I have this code and for some reason it won't get inserted into my database. It's basically taking an array, turning it into a string and then submit the values. 
(If you need me to edit to show my whole code, I will do so)

Code I am having issues with down below

```
$array = array($RaceNumber,$Track,$Num,$HorseName,$Odds,$Color,$Jockey,$Trainer,$PostTime,$Course,$RaceDistance,$Win,$Place,$Show);

for ($a=0; $a<$Num; $a++) {
$dataArray=array($RaceNumber[$a],$Track[$a],$Num[$a],$HorseName[$a],$Odds[$a],$Color[$a],$Jockey[$a],$Trainer[$a],$PostTime[$a],$Course[$a],$RaceDistance[$a],$Win[$a],$Place[$a],$Show[$a]);

$dataArray--;
for ($j=0; $j<$Num; $j++) {

    $RaceNumber=$dataArray[0];
    $Track=$dataArray[1];
    $Num=$dataArray[2];
    $HorseName=$dataArray[3];
    $Odds=$dataArray[4];
    $Color=$dataArray[5];
    $Jockey=$dataArray[6];
    $Trainer=$dataArray[7];
    $PostTime=$dataArray[8];
    $Course=$dataArray[9];
    $RaceDistance=$dataArray[10];
    $Win=$dataArray[11];
    $Place=$dataArray[12];
    $Show=$dataArray[13];
    $sql="INSERT INTO `$Date` (RaceNumber,Track,HorseNum,HorseName,Odds,Color,JockeyName,TrainerName,PostTime,Course,RaceDistance,Win,Place,Show) VALUES ('$RaceNumber','$Track','$Num','$HorseName','$Odds','$Color','$Jockey','$Trainer','$PostTime','$Course','$RaceDistance','$Win','$Place','$Show')";
    echo $sql;
    mysqli_query($query2,$sql);
    }
  }
```

when I echo my `$sql` I get

`INSERT INTO 2018-09-20 (RaceNumber,Track,HorseNum,HorseName,Odds,Color,JockeyName,TrainerName,PostTime,Course,RaceDistance,Win,Place,Show) VALUES ('1','FingerLakes','1','','','Red','','','','Dirt','','none','none','none')`

But when I do my query, it isn't inserting into database.

Part of my code where I create the datatable

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $Date = $_POST['date'];

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$Date` (
    `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `RaceNumber` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Track` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `HorseNum` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `HorseName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Odds` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Color` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `JockeyName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `TrainerName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `PostTime` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Course` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `RaceDistance` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Win` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Place` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Show` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
;
$query2 = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','Races');   

$z= mysqli_query($query2, $sql) or die("Table already exist.. please try again");
echo "Your Table ".$Date." is successfully created <br/>";
$RaceNum = $_POST['RaceNum'];
$i=1;
```

I am receiving in my error log of

`2018-09-20 16:00:59 9444 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'max_value' at position 4 to have type varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).`

Comment: After `mysqli_query(` use error reporting. Also, that can't be your output the date is not in backticks, without backticks that is an invalid name.

Comment: That really is wrong style. Please read about the advantages of using the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" to prevent the huge security issues you open with your current approach.

Comment: @user3783243 got nothing

Comment: Check your http servers error log file, that is where php logs errors to usually.

Comment: @arkascha I know that I have to do PDO's but right now, I'm just setting things up so then I can go and change it all into that.

Comment: Did you use the function, with the connection link? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php Is `$query2` really your connection?

Comment: You are using `INSERT INTO 2018-09-20`, do you have **2018-09-20** table in your database?

Comment: This is why I should've posted my whole code i guess. 
@user3783243 yes

Comment: @mwaseema Yes, early in this code i have it create the table with current date

Comment: `INSERT INTO 2018-09-20 (` would cause an error so either, you don't execute that or you are misusing the error reporting.

Comment: I get this in my error log 
2018-09-20 16:00:59 9444 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.column_stats: expected column 'max_value' at position 4 to have type varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).
Not exactly sure what this means, updating my code above

Comment: @user3783243 it's actually `INSERT INTO ``2018-09-20 ``but i had to take those off bc it ruins with the editing

Comment: you are using a column named `Show` that's a reserved keyword in mysql, add backquotes to it and the insert query should work, although I must say the you shouldn't name your table with only digits and hyphens..

Comment: @mrbm thank you!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @mrbm if you want to reply that as an Answer, i'll green it, thanks!

Comment: sure, you're welcome !

Comment: @AustinViens-DeRuisseau That would have been reported with the error reporting function. You should look into your usage with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a column named `Show` that's a reserved keyword in mysql, add backquotes to it and the insert query should work.

It's worth noting that you shouldn't name your table with only digits and hyphens.

For reference here is the complete list of the reserved keywords:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html